# android:listSelector after notifyDataSetChanged(), color disappears

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm having a slight issue here with this listview:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/employees_list"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                    android:paddingRight="1dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/borderlist"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
                    android:listSelector="#48ad82"
                    android:layout_below="@id/employees_header">
 </ListView>
```

Which contains this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/row_employee"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="13dp"
    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_employee"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_employeename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/radio_employee"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:focusable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT2: Simplifying the question as much as I can:

When I select an element on the list, it changes color due to the android:listSelector. When I call notifyDataSetChanged() in the code, that color disappears until I scroll the list up or down. How can I make the color not disappear?

Someone answered to use a selector like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#48ad82" />
    </shape>
</item>
    <item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#unselectedcolor" />
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

**I set this selector as a background. It does not work at all. The color of the elements do not even change when I select them**

Edit1: To specify, the color re-appears when I scroll the list.

Comment: I am not understand the main problem. Can you please simplify your question...

Comment: did you find a way to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your RelativeLayout:

```
android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector"
```

Add this file to your drawable folder

**list_item_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#48ad82" />
    </shape>
</item>
    <item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#unselectedcolor" />
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

EDIT: And remove android:listSelector="#48ad82" from your ListView

Comment: That doesn't work at all. The state_focused color doesn't show.